# I'm using celery 4.4. There are options like --without-gossip. How can I set this parameter in a worker?

Tags: python, celery

I need a universal solution to have this option inside the code, so these options with app.worker_main and celery worker --without-gossip are not suitable.

I saw this example:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(broker='amqp://')

def add_worker_arguments(parser):
     parser.add_argument(
         '--enable-my-option', action='store_true', default=False,
         help='Enable custom option.',
     ),
app.user_options['worker'].add(add_worker_arguments)

All bootsteps will now receive this argument as a keyword argument to Bootstep.__init__:

from celery import bootsteps

class MyBootstep(bootsteps.Step):

     def __init__(self, parent, enable_my_option=False, **options):
         super().__init__(parent, **options)
         if enable_my_option:
             party()

app.steps['worker'].add(MyBootstep)
```

But it adds a new option to the employee, rather than changing an existing one

I saw that they have the default value false when they are not called. How can I change this value to true?

```
fopts.add_argument(
        '--without-gossip', action='store_true', default=False,
)
```